# How to change the position of an element in flex container?

Tags: html, css

I want to take element 3 to the right of the screen. This is an example from `W3School`:

```css
.flex-container {
      display: flex;
      background-color: DodgerBlue;
    }
    
    .flex-container > div {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<h1>Create a Flex Container</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
</div>
```

How can I do this when I'm using a flex display?

Comment: just use margin-left auto on the 3 child .flex-container > div:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat a hack, but it does work [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4r7oaL1/)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container > div:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

Example
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't call this a hack, `margin: auto;` has been used for many years and it's simple and effective. Alternatively you could just use `align-self: flex-end` which basically does the same thing, but I wouldn't consider this a hack :)

Comment: ok lel..........

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) propriety of flexbox, like below, as an example:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container > div:nth-child(3) {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Create a Flex Container</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
      display: flex;
      background-color: DodgerBlue;
    }
    
    .flex-container > div {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 30px;
    }

.flex-container > div:nth-child(3){
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Create a Flex Container</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
</div>
```